# Time locking in booking

Tags: php, time, locking

I'm on implementing a booking site. All the booking data goes to an XML file.

If multiple users try to book at the same time for the same day, how can I lock the time that the first user selected?

Comment: Can you provide samples of code you have tried?

Comment: @StevenFarley i haven't tried yet, coz does not know how to implement.

Comment: We will not do your work for you.  You must show some effort here.  Try *something*.  *Anything*

Comment: @Charles i don't want you to work for me..i'm just asking a way that how to implement it.i think that is what stack overflow meant for. isn't it??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use one flag as locked and make is as Zero when it is available.. When the first person book.. you can change it into 1 and show the message as locked by checking this flag.. 
**fieldName (flag) - locked as default 0 in sql/xml node..**

For your understanding,

*create one new field as locked in DB/XML NODE be default value as 0... and when the first person book you have check that field as 0 or 1.. if it is 0 then after booking you change that field to 1.. ok.. Now when second person come to book you have to check that locked field is 0 or 1 if 1 you should not book and inform the person that it was booked*

For locking while selecting itself.. follow the following,

**You can do one thing.. you could lock it as 1 for 5 - 10 mins when selected.. and after that if it is booked keep it as 1 no pblm.. or else change it into 0.. got it??????????
or create one more field for booked and use locked for selection...... check booked.. if not check locked**

Comment: i'm not clear about what u said. do you mind explaning it a bit

Comment: what if the user play with times by not booking the selected times

Comment: edited my answer briefly.. check into it..

Comment: ok. vinoth.. what if user leave the time as if selected?

Comment: You can do one thing.. you could lock it as 1 for 5 - 10 mins when selected.. and after that if it is booked keep it as 1 no pblm.. or else change it into 0.. got it?????????? or create one more field for booked and use locked for selection...... check booked.. if not check locked ..

Comment: Thanks. But one more question

how do i know the node reference which i was updated in xml?
how do i update node value to 0 without knowing the correct node??

Comment: You update only one node for the particular ticket and check it while listing ticket... please have some try... and check.. If my answer is useful.. please vote and accept my answer..